# MS SQL Server - WITH ROLLUP & GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, group-by

qq:

I have a code as below which works fine, but I would also add WITH ROLLUP & WITH CUBE options (2 different cases.). Any idea how?. In comments my ideas which unfortunately do not work...

```
SELECT 
    --ISNULL(EventDate, 'Total'), DOES NOT WORK
    DATEPART(YEAR, EventDate) AS EventYear,
    DATEPART(MONTH, EventDate) AS EventMonth,
    COUNT (*) AS [Number of events]
FROM 
    tblEvent
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, EventDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, EventDate) -- WITH ROLLUP DOESN NOT WORK
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, EventDate)DESC, 
    DATEPART(MONTH, EventDate)DESC
```

Comment: show sample data and your query output

Comment: You haven't really explained what "doesn't work" means or how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    --ISNULL(EventDate, 'Total'), DOES NOT WORK
    DATEPART(YEAR, EventDate) AS EventYear,
    DATEPART(MONTH, EventDate) AS EventMonth,
    COUNT (*) AS [Number of events]
FROM 
    tblEvent
GROUP BY ROLLUP(
    DATEPART(YEAR, EventDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, EventDate))
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, EventDate)DESC, 
    DATEPART(MONTH, EventDate)DESC
```